# Delete single array object in mongodb uing $unset

Tags: mongodb

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yv6vkGyrUS-

https://mongoplayground.net/p/vm314GoexjE

```
[
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("4b253b067525f35f94b60a31"),
  "age": 30,
  "favorite book": [
  "Cat's Cradle",
  "Foundation Trilogy",
  "Ender's Game"
   ],
"location": "Wisconsin",
"name": "joe",
"sex": "male"
}
]
```

output delete any element with based on condition

```
"favorite book": [
  "Cat's Cradle",
  "Foundation Trilogy"
   ]
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423873/deleting-a-single-object-from-an-array-of-objects-in-mongodb/13424041

Comment: but i want del only array of obj a=[1,2,3] del a[1] now a=[1,3]... favbook=[1,2,3]  del favbook[0] , favbook=[2,3] etc..

Comment: $pull: {
      "favorite book":  ??   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$pull` operator

```
db.collection.update({
    { _id : id },
    { $pull: { "favorite book": "Ender's Game" } }
});
```

If you want to remove two or more elements from the array "list", you can do that with $pull operator, as well:

```
db.collection.update({
    { _id : id },
    { $pull: { "favorite book" : { $in : [ "Foundation Trilogy", "Ender's Game"] } } }
});
```

Please check [How do I remove a string from an array in a mongodb document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002691/how-do-i-remove-a-string-from-an-array-in-a-mongodb-document/32002845)

Comment: its possible with unset ?

Comment: Yes. I think. But You will use the index of the element. But, it doesn’t remove the array element. Instead, it sets it to null. Check out https://www.mongodbtutorial.org/mongodb-crud/mongodb-remove-field-unset/